# Full-screen desktop application with QML

Tags: qt4, fullscreen, qml

I have experience with developing rich user interface application with flex and AS3. However the issue is its very hard to use existing c++ business logic with these flex apps. With the advent of QML, I am curious whether its possible to reuse the c++ business logic with QT for rich UI apps.

I want to know whether its possible to develop full screen rich user interface applications(which are becoming more and more common especially in mobile devices) for the desktop. For example(http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/07/creating-full-screen-flex-applications/) Adobe has the Flash Player which can be used in full screen mode and runs content written in AS3. Is it possible to write similar applications using QT/QML?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you would like to use business logic written on C++ and some QML user interface you can use `QDeclarativeView` inside your application. It's just a regular Qt widget so it has method `showFullScreen()`. Actually this class is like "qmlviewer inside your application".

So you'll get something like this:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeView>
#include <QtCore/QUrl>

int main(int _argc, char * _argv[])
{
    QApplication app(_argc, _argv);

    QDeclarativeView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/MyGui.qml"));    // if your QML files are inside 
                                               // application resources

    view.showFullScreen();    // here we show our view in fullscreen

    return app.exec();
}
```

You can find more information [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdeclarativeview.html).

Comment: I logged in to +1 this. I scoured the internet for an example just on how to get a QML file loaded into a Qt application for about 20 minutes until I happened to find this. Maybe I need to learn how to use Google better.

Anyway, thank you so much!

Answer (score 41):

There is also a QML-only way to go fullscreen.
You can use this if you are not using QDeclarativeView but QQmlApplicationEngine, since the latter doesn't inherits QWidget and has not the method showFullScreen().

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    visibility: "FullScreen"
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Button {
        text: "exit fullscreen"
        onClicked: window.visibility = "Windowed"
    }
}
```

But it's important to use ApplicationWindow as the root-element and not Rectangle. For ApplicationWindow you have to import QtQuick.Controls.

Comment: Worked well for me, but note that there is a bug which makes fullscreen QtQuick `MenuBar`s not work correctly (at least on Windows).

Comment: To use the window maximized, you can use: `height: Screen.height; width: Screen.width`

Comment: There's also enums available, instead of those strings, `Window.FullScreen`, etc. In Qt 5.11 this also matches the value you read back from the property (ie, dont try to test against "Windowed" as a value, itll never happen)

Answer (score 9):

When using QQmlApplicationEngine in c++ you can do something like this in QML:

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: mainWindow

    Component.onCompleted: {
        mainWindow.showFullScreen();
    }
}
```

Tested with QT5.8

Answer (score 9):

Here is yet another variation from previous answers, but this uses the (default Qt Quick Application - Empty) Window QML type and a Qt enum:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    objectName: "mainWindow"
    visible: true
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window
    color: "black"
    visibility: Qt.WindowFullScreen // << the solution
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Qt has [qmlviewer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmlviewer.html).

To run it in fullscreen:

```
$ qmlviewer -fullscreen -frameless file.qml
```

Also there is a [tutorial](http://wiki.meego.com/QML/Full-screen_applications) of creating fullscreen applications with QML.
And [components](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/03/10/qml-components-for-desktop/) for desktop widgets.

Comment: I need that tut actually, but it's not reachable for me. Is there a problem with the link please?

Comment: Meego wiki looks dead. Try to find something there https://wiki.qt.io/QtDesktopComponents

Answer (score 0):

hello friend i know that its late for 10 years but i hope to help some one.
for set windows to be Full Screen at android and others in QML/quick you can use this Code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
id: root
width: Screen.width
height: Screen.height
visibility:Window.FullScreen
Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log(width+":"+height)
}
visible: true
title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
```