# QScreen geometry() api is giving wrong values for the resolutions 2736 x 1824 and 2560 x 1600

Tags: c++, qt, qml, resolution, screen-resolution

// Unable to resize qt application according to some high resolution screen size ?

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QScreen>
#include "rearend.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    //qmlRegisterType<RearEnd>("io.backside",1,0,"RearEnd");
    QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    QRect  screenGeometry = screen->geometry();
    int height = screenGeometry.height();
    int width = screenGeometry.width();

    qDebug() << "height = " << height;
    qDebug() << "width = " << width;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    RearEnd *myClass = new RearEnd;
    myClass->setHeight(height);
    myClass->setWidth(width);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("RearEnd", myClass);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);
    return app.exec();
}
```

// I'm trying to create a qt application which can be deploy on any device of any resolution.So my qt application uses QScreen geometry() api and gets height and width of the primary screen.These values are then passed to qml where different components like layouts,layout alignment positions,rectangles , buttons etc resize themselves according to screen resolution.And the above code is working fine for many resolutions like 2048 x 1536, 1920 x 1080, 1680 x 1050, 800 x 600 etc.But they are not working for 2736 x 1824 and 2560 x 1600.I'm printing logs while I run my qt application.When I set resolution 1920 x 1080, it is showing me width = 1920 & height = 1080.But when I set resolution as 2736 x 1824 in logs it is showing width = 1368 & height = 912.Similarly when I set the resolution as 2560 x 1600, in logs it is showing width = 1280 & height = 800

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the values you get for _2736 x 1824 and 2560 x 1600_? What Qt version are you using?

Comment: And which OS / WIndowManager are you using?

Comment: Why you can't just create QML view in [full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9025611/1387438) and let the layout take the charge?

Comment: `Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling` already do the work. You don't have to scale the elements in your application.

Comment: I'm using Qt Creator 4.10.0 which is Based on Qt 5.13.1 (MSVC 2017, 32 bit).The Windows edition of my system is Windows 10 pro

Comment: QDeclarativeView  has been deprecated.The QtDeclarative module has been available until Qt 5.6 but has been renamed to Qt Quick 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the solution.I commented this code "QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)" & it worked for me.Seems there was some dpi issue which was not working for high end resolutions.